# turtle.setpos () xy axis included in a while loop

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have been playing with turtle and trying to draw a grid of squares along the x and y axis.

I make use of a while loop to draw squares along the x axis however I'm unable to get squares being drawn along the y axis. If anyone is able to provides some guidance, will be great.

Thanks

```
import turtle

def square(x,y):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setpos(x,y)
    turtle.pendown()
    for i in range(4):
        turtle.forward(60)
        turtle.right(90)

y = 300
x = -100
while x < 300:
x += 100

while y < 300:
    y -= 100
    if y == 0:
        break
square(x, y)
```

Comment: `y` is 300 and as a result your second while loop never runs. You also likely want to call `square()` inside each loop

Comment: Pls post images or screenshots of what you’re trying to achieve and what you actually get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `y` is 300 and as a result your second `while` loop never runs. You also likely want to call `square()` inside each loop. This should work a little more like you hope. You might have to adjust the starting values of x and y and the increments to get the squares drawn as you like:

```py
import turtle

def square(x,y):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setpos(x,y)
    turtle.pendown()
    for i in range(4):
        turtle.forward(60)
        turtle.right(90)

y = 300
x = -100

while x < 300:
    x += 100
    square(x, y)

while y > 0:
    y -= 100
    square(x, y)
```